# Formal notation for a required statement

Tags: notation

Is there a formal notation to distinguish an equality that is a true statement, e.g.,

> [...] and hence,
>   $$
>     x = x^2 - 1
>   $$
>   [...]

from a demand, e.g.,

> [...] so we require
>   $$
>   x \stackrel{!}{=} x^2 - 1
> $$
>   [...]

?

The same thing could apply to membership to sets $x\stackrel{!}{\in}\mathbb{R}$ and more.

I've seen the exclamation mark syntax once, and I faintly remember having seen some other notation, but I'm not sure if any of this is commonly used.

Comment: I've once seen $\stackrel{?}{=}$ in _Concrete Mathematics_ to represent an equality we are trying to prove/disprove; but I've not encountered notation like this elsewhere. +1 for the interesting question!

Comment: I have sometimes used this notation in my private notes. I suppose I may have learned it from somewhere, but if so I don't remember, and it sure isn't very common or standardized. (Though I won't rule out the existence of subcultures where it *is* common.)

Comment: I've seen $\equiv$ used for identity (i.e. true for all values of the argument) as opposed to equation (which may or may not be true for any values of the argument).

Comment: I see a rotated form of $\displaystyle\; \; \stackrel{..}{\stackrel{!}{=}} \; \;$ pretty often...

Comment: I've both seen and used $\stackrel{!}{=}$ to denote a requirement.

Comment: I can imagine this being useful in a lecture, to help the audience follow the logic between formulas written  on the board. I don't see much need for it in a paper: I'd rather have the meaning conveyed to me by the text surrounding the formulas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically  if I were you I would write the exclamation mark. If you fear that it is not understandable then remark in your text that this should specify that it is a demand and not a statement.

I think a lot of mathematicians use the exclamation mark in the sense you think of it. However, I don't think that it is "official" notation (like $e$ for the Euler number or so...).

---

(Although it doesn't exactly go for the question itself as the following deals with *statements* rather than *demands* I want to shortly mention here an)

**Interesting note:** Frege (the founder of modern logic)  [introduced](http://archive.org/stream/functionundbegr00freggoog#page/n30/mode/2up) a special sign to indicate that what follows it is an assertion rather than a truth. This sign is "$\vdash$".

So he would write at the beginning of a proof:

$\vdash 1+1=2$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

To say that he states that $1+1=2$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is true.
Contrariwise

$1+1=2$ in $\mathbb{R}$,

is for Frege a truth value (or to be more accuarte: the Truth itself.)

Actually people in mathematical logic use this very sign to indicate tautologies. However, I don't really know if there is any connection between this use and Frege...

Comment: I like the way it's done in computer science: $$ e := \lim_{n \to \infty} \left ( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right )^n$$
where $:=$ denotes variable assignment. It doesn't look beautiful but it leaves the reader with no doubt.

Comment: @Matt But isn't that more to define something rather than demand that equality holds?

Comment: Yes! Sorry, I misread the question.